# mvc regex to validate numbers as 00-99

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc3 and i want a particular requirement that the mvc validation uses numbers from 0-99 so that i have the regex as

[RegularExpression("[0-9]{1,2}$")]

Now i want a particular requirement that the numbers from 0-9 must pass validation if it is typed as 01,02,....,09 and the rest of the numbers between as 10-99 should pass validation as a two digit number.

Please help me on this regex. I have googled it but to no avail.

can anyone suggest a regex for this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just matching

```
"[0-9][0-9]"
```

should fit your requirements exactly.
It only matches if single numbers are typed in the form of 01; 02; 03 etc and matches all two digit numbers